# Null selection error on Bryntum Kanban Task click

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I am working on integrating the Bryntum Kanban board into an EXTJS application. In the top toolbar of the kanban, I have an ExtJS combobox that changes the view so that users can view their private taskboard as well as the taskboard for their groups. (Users can be in more than one group) When the view is changed, both the statestore that populates the columns of the taskboard and the userstore that populates the userpicker need to reload, as well as the taskstore. The problem is that after the view is changed, clicking on a task throws two errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "getRange", this.selected is null
    ExtJS 2
    relayMethod http://dev.southern-air.com/javascript/taskboard/taskboard-all-debug.js:6471
    map ExtJS
    relayMethod http://dev.southern-air.com/javascript/taskboard/taskboard-all-debug.js:6470
    deselectAll http://dev.southern-air.com/javascript/taskboard/taskboard-all-debug.js:6446
    deselectAll http://dev.southern-air.com/javascript/taskboard/taskboard-all-debug.js:7431
    onDragStarting http://dev.southern-air.com/javascript/taskboard/taskboard-all-debug.js:7532
    ExtJS 4
    getDragData http://dev.southern-air.com/javascript/taskboard/taskboard-all-debug.js:4896
    ExtJS 86
ext-all-debug.js:200495:9
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "getRange", this.selected is null
    ExtJS 2
    deselectAllInOtherSelectionModels http://dev.southern-air.com/javascript/taskboard/taskboard-all-debug.js:6465
    each ExtJS
    forEachSelModel http://dev.southern-air.com/javascript/taskboard/taskboard-all-debug.js:6475
    deselectAllInOtherSelectionModels http://dev.southern-air.com/javascript/taskboard/taskboard-all-debug.js:6464
    deselectAllInOtherViews http://dev.southern-air.com/javascript/taskboard/taskboard-all-debug.js:7385
    onTaskClick http://dev.southern-air.com/javascript/taskboard/taskboard-all-debug.js:7381
    ExtJS 2
ext-all-debug.js:200495:9
```

Here is the code for the change listener on the combobox:

```
change: function (field, newValue) {
    var ts = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('taskstore');
    var ss = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('statestore');
    var us = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('userstore');
    var taskboard = field.up('mytaskboard');
    console.log(taskboard);
    ts.getProxy().setExtraParam('view', newValue);
    ss.getProxy().setExtraParam('view', newValue);
    us.getProxy().setExtraParam('view', newValue);
    taskboard.deselectAll();
    ss.reload({
        callback: function () {
            // taskboard.deselectAll();
            taskboard.refresh();
            us.reload({
                callback: function () {
                    taskboard.userMenu.picker.refresh();
                    ts.reload({
                        callback: function () {
                            console.log(taskboard);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Is there anything that I need to do before I reload the stores to ensure that this error is not thrown? If anyone has also had this problem I'd appreciate your solutions. I have tried deselecting all before reloading, as you can see in the code above, but that doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting, I was able to find a solution that seems to be working. I had to add the following line to the change listener before reloading the stores:

```
delete field.up('mytaskboard').selModel;
```

This line deletes all the selection models from the taskboard, which were the things that were causing the problem in the first place. Now the views change and everything works as expected. I am still interested to know if this may cause other issues down the line though.